# Python maneuvering with nested generators

Tags: python, iterator, generator, yield

I have some codes like this:

```py
class A:
  def __iter__(self):
    for i in range(100):
      yield i

class B:
  def __init__(self, src):
    self.src = src
  def __iter__(self):
    for i in self.src:
      yield i * 2

class C:
  def __init__(self, src1, src2):
    self.src1 = src1
    self.src2 = src2
  def __iter__(self):
    for i, j in zip(self.src1, self.src2):
      yield i + j

a = A()
b = B(a)
c = C(a, b)
it = iter(c)
next(it)
```

What I want to do is to decompose the calling chain when invoking `next(it)`. More specifically, I want to execute some new code after the `yield` in each class without modifying the class codes. Ideally the new code prints in which class the `yield` is executed. Is this a possible thing?

Comment: Do you understand that when you combine `a` and `b` into `c`, the `zip()` will get alternating elements from `a`?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want to do. Can you give an example of what you want to execute after the `yield`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a subclass for each of the generator class with a wrapper `__iter__` method that prints in which class `yield` is to be executed before yielding from the `__iter__` method of the superclass. Since `yield` pauses the execution of the generator and returns control back to the caller, the wrapper should print such an output before, not after, yielding:

```
def print_yields(cls):
    class wrapper(cls):
        def __iter__(self):
            iterator = super().__iter__()
            for i in iterator:
                print(f'yielding {i} from class {cls.__name__} with iterator {id(iterator):x}')
                yield i
    return wrapper

a = print_yields(A)()
b = print_yields(B)(a)
c = print_yields(C)(a, b)
for i in c:
    print(i)
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/UprightWebbedArtificialintelligence

Comment: It's the same instance `a` being used as a generator, so you can't expect different output by printing the ids of the instances. What's different in the two calls are the iterators created for the two different iterations, so the ids of the iterators are what you can output to differentiate the two. I've updated the answer accordingly then.